# Thymeleaf layout fragment not working in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

In spring boot, the layout came out properly with the following settings, but it does not work after changing to webflux.

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {
    ApplicationContext context;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {

    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(this.context);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setCheckExistence(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ISpringWebFluxTemplateEngine thymeleafTemplateEngine() {
        SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver thymeleafReactiveViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(thymeleafTemplateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.viewResolver(thymeleafReactiveViewResolver());
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
    }
}
```

layout_main.html

```
<body>
        <div class="layout-main" ng-app="mainApp">
            <header th:replace="fragment/header :: header"></header>
            <div class="content">
                <section layout:fragment="content"></section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <th:block layout:fragment="js-end"></th:block>
</body>
```

chat.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layout/layout_main">

<section layout:fragment="content" ng-controller="chatController" class="content-chat-container">
    <nav th:replace="~{app/chat/fragment/nav_chat :: nav}"></nav>
    <div class="app-wrapper">

    </div>
</section>
```

When opening chat.html, the layout:decorator part is not properly processed, so layout_main is not included and the View appears.